# Recently I was testing a site and I found two API keys of segment

Tags: debugging, testing

I was wondering if any impact can be done by segment keys?

I recently started testing bugs on websites and as I was testing a web site, I found two sets of API keys that lead me to segment, but I'm not sure what can be done with it I read few docs but couldn't determine if there is any impact.

Comment: What is "segment"?

Comment: segment.com or segment.io